# Where is the story of Lord Śiva beheading Brahmā who was in the form of a stag (deer) found?

Tags: shiva, brahma, brahmanas, rudra, nakshatra

Prajāpati Brahmā in a desire to create more perfect and beautiful beings in the universe was obsessed with his beautiful daughter Rohiṇī.  Sensing her father’s attraction and intention she assumed the form of a deer and fled.
He kept chasing her in the form of a Stag. Lord Śiva sensing the incestuous intentions beheaded the stag, which became the constellation Mṛgaśiras (Deer-head).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, everything from your question is actually false. The true is:-

1. **Lord Shiva beheading Brahma's fifth head**

The Shiva, Skanda and Linga Puranas are clearly mentioned about this event. But, Rohini is didn't existed during this time, because this event is happened at the start of creation.

2. **Rohini is Brahma's granddaughter and who is the real deer beheaded by Shiva**

Well, many Puranas mentiones that Rohini is Daksha's daughter. Daksha is Brahma's son, so Rohini is Brahma's granddaughter.

And the deer is actually Yagna Purusha. Here the Sati Khanda from Shiva Purana mentioned it.

> 36-37. The sacrifice was terrified on hearing the sound, “O I am doomed”, he thought. He was trembling with the legs shaking. His lustre disappeared. He ran in the form of a deer. The heroic Bhadra. with a half curved arrow, decapitated him.

The above reference says that Yajnapurusha was beheaded by Bhadra (Virabhadra), not Lord Shiva himself.

*(Note: But, your question is not actually look likes a actual question)*

---

Ok, that's it.